# How to create base for plastic bag packaging?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, packaging

[image]

I have measurement for this type of other bag packaging and i want to know how can i create base in illustrator for this bag.

Measurements are as follow, height is 19, width is 29 and length is 35 all measurements are in centimeter. please help me asap.

Comment: Hi Devang. Please give us a bit more: what do you mean with a 'base', what have you tried, and why can't the manufacturer of the bag you're going to design provide you with a base? If you want to know more about how to ask a good question, please have a look at the [help] or [this page](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the die-lines from the print-shop. There may be even some online for free, but I doubt that they are the same the one the printshop uses.

Btw don't forget the design needs to be in CMYK